# Trying to create a a reveal footer in React, footer ignoring other divs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to implement a reveal on scroll footer much like: https://codepen.io/thomasbobs/pen/KGyvMx

The problem is when I set the footer to `position: fixed;` it ignores the positioning of the relatively positioned divs and goes over them.

My main.js:

```
<>
    <Modal
        show={isModalOpen}
        modalInfo={modalInfo}
        setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen}
        viewport={props.viewport}
    />
    <main id="main">
        <About aboutRef={aboutRef}/>
        <Skills skillsRef={skillsRef}/>
        <Portfolio setIsModalOpen={setIsModalOpen} setModalInfo={setModalInfo} projectRef={projectRef}/>
        <Contact contactRef={contactRef}/>
    </main>
</>
```

My App.js

```
<div className="App">
    <Navbar isMobile={isMobile} isTop={isTop} activeRef={activeRef} progress={progress}/>
    <div className="canvas-wrapper">
        <Canvas colorManagement camera={{position: [-5,2,50]}}>
            <HeaderContent/>
            <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
            <Stars/>
        </Canvas>
    </div>
    <div className="main-wrapper">
        <Main isMobile={isMobile} viewport={viewport} activeRef={activeRef} setActiveRef={setActiveRef} setIsTop={setIsTop}/>
    </div>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

My Main-wrapper and Footer scss:

```
.main-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
}
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `height: 100%` and add background-color for `main-wrapper`

```
.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}
```